# error_log(); не создает указанный файл PHP

Tags: php

В общем написал свой класс обработчика исключений(ошибок).

В нем есть метод, который выполняет функцию `error_log("сообщение", 3, "путь к файлу");`, то есть логирует ошибку в указанный файл.
Проблема в следующем: при выбросе исключения не создается файл, то есть его нужно создавать вручную. Исключения срабатывают, обработчик их обрабатывает как надо, но файл не создается.

Если я создам его вручную по указанному пути, то предыдущие ошибки там все отобразятся. Не понимаю в чем дело.

Где то вычитал что дело в правах на этот каталог/файл, на создание там чего-либо, но

```
substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms('мой *каталог*/*файл в каталоге*')), -4);
```

выдает мне *0777*/*0666* соответственно.

Пользуюсь openserver - php7.4+apache. IDE - pStorm.

Comment: Покажите, что внутри функции error_log

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.error-log.php

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev error_log("{$message} | {$file} | {$line}", 3, ROOT."/errors.log"); Константу если что видит, пробовал и с ней и без неё.